# excuting from terminal configure fails

Tags: linux, command-line, installation, terminal

I am trying to install XFe 1.33 downloaded from http://roland65.free.fr/xfe/index.php?page=docs 
But when I am doing

`./configure`

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/local/home/vquang/Desktop/xfe-1.33':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I run into that error
I check my gcc compiler and it replies me that I have the latest package installed

Could someone help me overcome this little issue ?

```
configure:3662: $? = 0
configure:3651: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i386-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/sh$
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
configure:3662: $? = 0
configure:3651: gcc -V >&5
gcc: '-V' option must have argument
configure:3662: $? = 1
configure:3651: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: unrecognized option '-qversion'
gcc: no input files
configure:3662: $? = 1
configure:3682: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3704: gcc    conftest.c  -lX11 >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3708: $? = 1
configure:3746: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "xfe"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xfe"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.33"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "xfe 1.33"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "xfe"
| #define VERSION "1.33"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int | main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3751: error: in `/usr/local/home/daniel/Desktop/xfe-1.33':
configure:3753: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `config.log`?

Answer (score 0):

The useful part is:

```
configure:3682: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3704: gcc    conftest.c  -lX11 >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
```

You are missing `libX11.so`, or it is not in your linker path, or you have recently installed it and not run `ldconfig` to update the configuration. It would be odd if you had a working X environment without this library.
You might have better luck over here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/libx11-so-6-not-found